# helm secrets time parsing error in YAML file

Tags: python, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run the command:
`helm secrets install --dry-run --debug https://...foobar.tgz -f values.yaml -f secrets.yaml`

and I'm getting the following output:
`parsing time "2019-12-08 15:20:36" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse " 15:20:36" as "T"`

In my secrets file the time is written the following way: `lastmodified: 2019-12-08 15:20:36`

anyone have a solution?

Also, I want to run the command in python, is there a reason the command will run in my cmd but not in my pyhton file?

Comment: The ISO 8601 time format wants the letter `T` between the date and the time; your existing `secrets.yaml` file has a space there instead.  Can you change the contents of the YAML file?  If not, why not, and can you include some of the consuming code (what _actually_ produces that error)?

Comment: It solved it, but now I have the same problem only when I run it in a python file...